# Проблема с новым пользователем

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Создал нового пользователя и сделал ему рабочий каталог такими командами:

```
sudo useradd username
sudo mkdir /home/username
sudo passwd username
sudo chown username /home/username 
sudo chgrp username /home/username
sudo adduser username sudo
```

Но когда захожу под этим пользователем, то не оказываюсь в его домашней директории и терминал выглядит немного странно (без указания пользователя и имени компьютера):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Что я делаю не так ?**

Comment: А зачем надо было создавать папку и менять права?

Comment: При создании пользователя можно воспользоваться ключом -m, при этом домашний каталог создастся автоматически. useradd -m user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из man useradd: `useradd` - низкоуровневая команда для добавления пользователей, в Debian вместо неё обычно стоит использовать `adduser`.

Кроме тех действий, что вы сделали, `adduser` сама создаёт домашний каталог пользователя и копирует туда *файлы настроек* из /etc/skel, назначает пользователю оболочку из `/etc/adduser.conf` и может выполнить другие инициализирующие действия, если они определены в `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local`.

И всё-таки после указанных вами действий вы должны были оказаться в домашней директории `/home/username`, чтобы убедиться в этом наберите `pwd`.

Answer (score 1):

`useradd` не создаёт домашний каталог пользователя, если вы не использовали параметр `-m`. С ним же - каталог создаётся автоматически. Вероятно, из-за того, что вы решили почему-то домашний каталог создать вручную, в файл `/etc/passwd` для вашего новоего пользователя не была добавлена запись о его домашнем каталоге. Проверить это вы можете выполнив команду `grep username /etc/passwd`.

Что бы дописать в файл `/etc/passwd` имя домашнего каталога для пользователя - выполните команду `usermod -d /home/username username`.

После этого - скопируйте в домашний каталог содержимое `/etc/skel`.